# Why doesn't Java's `String.toCharArray()` and `new String(char[])` methods accept a charset encoding?

Tags: java, string, encoding, character-encoding

Why doesn't Java's `String.toCharArray()` and `new String(char[])` methods accept a charset encoding?

If you're using `byte[]` you can optionally specify a charset using `String.getBytes(charset)` and `new String(byte[], charset)`.

I was wondering if there's a something about `char[]` and charset encodings I don't understand. Nothing particular in the Javadocs seems to explain the difference.

Comment: What is a `char`?

Comment: it's a Java basic type

Comment: Well, yeah. But what does it represent?

Comment: Yes, there is.  A charset is how you convert between bytes and chars.  A string is made of chars.  If you already have chars you don't need to convert them anymore.

Comment: Ahahaha. Lights on. Thank you!

Comment: I think @SotiriosDelimanolis is saying the answer is in [plain sight](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) in the Java language documentation. (UTF-16 code unit—similarly, for .NET, JavaScript, HTML, XML, etc.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These methods don't perform encoding, they simply represent a copy of the `String` instance's internal state.

Encoding is the process of converting logical glyphs to a numeric representation, a series of bytes. Think of a `String` as representing a sequence of Unicode glyphs. The `String` class has APIs to access these glyphs as 32-bit code points, or as a series of 16-bit values encoded with UTF-16-BE (which happens to be the string's native, internal representation), or as a series of bytes in a chosen encoding. You only need to specify the encoding in the last case.

Some encodings, like UTF-8, support all Unicode characters, while many others, like US-ASCII, support only a tiny subset. The `char[]`-based APIs don't allow specifying a different encoding (UTF-16-LE, or UTF-16 with a BOM) because one is sufficient, and promoting uniformity minimizes errors from mismatched encodings.

Comment: Ah, so `toCharArray` would be Java's internal UTF-16?

Comment: @JonathanS.Fisher Yes, exactly.